# Excel VBA - Copy shapes code not always working

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with some shapes that act as buttons.  On of these shapes has a macro assigned to it that does several things.  It creates a new sheet and does several things with this new sheet.  One of the things it does is copies a couple of different shapes that are hyperlinked to other sheets in the workbook.  The code works, but not always.  For some reason sometimes it doesn't copy either shape or might only copy one shape.  It works for both shapes about 80% of the time. Here is the section of the code that copies the shapes from other sheets.  Can anyone explain why it is not always working?

```
' Copy Index linked button from Calculator sheet
Sheets("Calculator").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 3").Copy
Range("L3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Copy Calculator linked button from Index sheet
Sheets("Index").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 1").Copy
Range("J3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: It's highly likely that the shape name is being changed somehow. When any named "thing" in Excel is copied, the name is also copied but is slightly changed by Excel. For example, copying named `Sheet1` creates named `Sheet1 (2)`. Unless you manage your shape names very carefully, this can easily be what's tripping you up. As an alternative, you can limit the scope of the shape's name (or any of Excel's named "things") to be local to a single worksheet instead of global for the whole workbook. If the shape's name is local, you could use the exact same name on different sheets.